# how to get grand total values for MoM% and YoY% while using lookup or table calcuation in tableau

Tags: tableau-api, lookup, mom

how to get grand total values for MoM% and YoY% while using lookup or table calcuation

Hi, in my tableau viz i need to get the MoM% and YoY% for each row item and display grand total as well.

1. I have tried using the quick table calculation of percent  difference for MoM.
2. I used the year over year growth from quick table
   calculation for YOY

Alternatively, i tried using the Lookup function to get the MoM% and YoY% as well. In both the approaches, the grand total value is blank. Can someone help me here.

Comment: Can you explain what a MoM% grand total would be, mathematically?

Comment: @Bernardo  lets say if we current report month is feb 2021, i need to individually show MoM starting from current year.. i,e  jan 2021 and feb 2021 and then in grandtotal (sum of jan + feb)/(sum dec 2020 + jan 2021) -1